# Run linux program from shell script with multi-line input

Tags: linux, shell

I want to run a specific program from a script which normally aks the user for some input (several times).

For example, when I start the program in the shell and my input would be:

```
t [ENTER]
3 [ENTER]
12 [ENTER]
e [ENTER]
```

where one has to wait after every line that the program wants the next input.

I guess there is a solution like

```
echo t | prog
echo 3 | prog
echo 12 | prog
echo e | prog
```

but after the first line the program runs with no input because of an empty buffer. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Prime use case for a here-document:

```
prog <<EOF
t
3
12
e
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

Guess it depends on what kind of shell you are using. With `bash` you can `echo` multiple lines like,

```
$ echo "t
> 3
> 12
> e" | prog
```

Answer (score -1):

The `read` command reads a single line, terminated by a newline.  You can include newlines in your echo:

`echo "t\n3\n12\ne" | prog`

Comment: `echo` does not handle escape sequences like `\n` unless `-e` option is specified on command line. The alternative solution is to use `printf`.

Comment: The `bash` built-in `echo` does not handle escape sequences without the `-e` option, which is a departure from the POSIX standard. Shells like `dash`, I assume, do not require `-e`. However, this just supports the suggestion to use `printf` instead.